# que esta mal? segun la consola me tira error en la primera llave despues de la condicion del if

Tags: javascript

Deberemos validar que entre los hobbies estén los strings "programación", "programacion" o "programar" o cada uno de los anteriores empezando con mayúscula.

En el caso que alguno de los anteriores esté, les mostraremos un alerta que diga: "Qué bueno que te guste la programación!!!".

En el caso que ninguno de los anteriores esté, les mostraremos un alerta que diga: "Qué lástima que no te guste la programación"

```js
    var hobbies = prompt("Ingrese su hobbies delimitados por coma espacio");
        
    
    hobbies = hobbies.split(", ");
        
        function amaProgramar(hobbies){
        if (this.hobbieUsuario.indexOf("programar" || "programacion" || "programación" || "Programar" || "Programacion" || "Programación" != -1){
         alert("Que bueno que te guste programar");
        } else {
          alert("Que lastima que no te guste programar");
         }
        }
```

Comment: Te falta cerrar un parentesis al final del `IF`

Comment: Tienes que cerrar el paréntesis aquí `if (this.hobbieUsuario.indexOf("programar" || "programacion" || "programación" || "Programar" || "Programacion" || "Programación") != -1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ademas de los parentesis que te señalan en los comentarios tienes mal declarada la variable `hobbieUsuario` esa variable no existe y al menos en este código no mandas a llamar la función, debería quedar así :

```js
var hobbies = prompt("Ingrese su hobbies delimitados por coma espacio");

hobbies = hobbies.split(",");

amaProgramar(hobbies);

function amaProgramar(hobbies){
 
 // arregglo con las palabras a buscar 
 var palablas = ["programacion","programar","programación", 
                "Programar","Programacion","Programación"];
 var encontradas=0;
 for(i=0;i<=palablas.length;i++ ){
  // buscamos cada una de ellas
   if ((this.hobbies.indexOf(palablas[i]))!=-1)  
   encontradas=encontradas+1;
 }
 
 if(encontradas==0)
    alert("Que lastima que no te guste programar");
  else
    alert("Que bueno que te guste programar");
  
 
}
```

Comment: Adicionalmente la funcion no se comporta como quiere, ya que si escribes la palabra en medio, no la reconoce. Recomiendo al OP utilizar includes en desmedro de indexOf

Comment: tienes toda la razón solo lo probé con la primer palabra, habrá que utilizar ciclos, editare la respuesta.

Comment: Ciclos no, basta cambiar el indexOf por un includes y listo! ;)

Comment: Es que `"programar" || "programacion || ..."` siempre retornará "programar" porque no es `false`.

Comment: Lo siento no se hacerlo con includes, de hecho si solo es cambiarlo definitivamente seria mas fácil ya que mi código entonces es mas complejo de lo que debería.... Por favor ponlo con includes :) y de paso aprendemos el OP y yo a usarlo...

Comment: Al usar `split` estas transformando la *string* a un vector. por lo que el usar `includes` no requiere de ciclos ya que este mismo método verifica si dentro de un vector existe alguno de los elementos pasados como argumentos

Comment: @Aprendiz me surgio la duda... includes no sirve solo para un valor? hice la prueba con otra opcion ademas de **programar** y no pasa la condicion

Comment: Una solución alternativa sería usar una expresión regular como la siguiente: `/(^|, *)(programacion|programación|programar)(, *|$)/i.test(hobbies)`. Donde `hobbies` sería la cadena sin hacer split.

Answer (score 0):

Edición, *dejo este ejemplo porque me parece que aún con las correcciones, el código del OP no obtendría el resultado esperado*

Coloco como ejemplo el siguiente script para tratar de orientar en una mejor respuesta a la que di en un primer momento

```js
    function amaHobbies() {
      let hobbie = ["hola", "Programar", "adios", "programación", "bye"]
      let resultado = hobbie.filter(elemento => elemento === "Programar" || elemento === "programación")
      let final = (resultado.length > 0) ? "Sí te gusta" : "No te gusta"
      return final
    } 
    
    console.log(amaHobbies())
```

Descripción del ejemplo:

- El método `filter` que genera un nuevo array con los elementos que cumplen la condición
- Para indicar si le gusta o no programar revise la longitud del vector resultante, si es 0 entonces ninguna de las palabras pasadas coincide con los valores almacenados en el vector, en caso contrario dado el operador `||` con que alguna de las palabras coincida entonces indicará que si le gusta programar
- Asigno a un operador ternario la verificación anterior, lo guardo en la variable `final`
- Como estoy dentro del contexto de una función entonces retorno a `final`
- Opcionalmente podemos cambiar el operador `||` por el operador `&&` para solicitar que solo diga que le gusta programar si todas las palabras existen en el nuevo vector creado

Comment: Como te comente más abajo, hice la prueba con tres palabras distintas, alternando el orden e incluyendo la palabra **programación** y no pasa la condición!

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera la elimino mientras reviso gracias por el dato

Comment: Dejo esta propuesta pues me parece aún con las correcciones al código del OP no termina de entregar el resultado esperado